# Go: why custom string type is not assignable to string using reflection?

Tags: go, reflection

Based on the [Go language spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability), two types should be assignable to each other if they share the same underlying types and at least one of them is not a named type.

However, I see that my custom string type is not assignable to string when checked using reflection. Why is this the case?

```golang
func main() {
    type mystr string // mystr have string underlying type
    var _ mystr = ""  // string is assignable to mystr in normal code

    m := reflect.TypeOf(mystr(""))
    s := reflect.TypeOf("")
    fmt.Println(m, s)                // main.mystr string
    fmt.Println(m.AssignableTo(s))   // false
    fmt.Println(s.AssignableTo(m))   // false
}
```

Comment: They share the same undelying types, but they are both  named types.

Comment: @BurakSerdar ah that makes sense. I assume only user defined types count as named types. Let me review again the definition of named types. Thanks.

Comment: Any type that has a name is a named type. For instance, `struct{}` is not a named type, but  with `type x struct{}` , `x` is a named type.

Comment: Because `var _ mystr = ""` works without needing any explicit conversion, I assumed that the reflect code should be equivalent and works too. But I guess rhs "" is just a type literal, which technically is not a string, but will be inferred as a string without any type declaration.